# On a second-order differential inequality involving the Dirichlet eta function

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, complex-numbers, riemann-zeta

After that I've tried understand the problem 6416 [1983, 60] A Second-Order Differential Inequality proposed by Sandford S. **Miller** in the **American Mathematical Monthly** (myself proposal is significantly different for other function and domain, inequality...but **Mocanu** and previous author have literature respect more general context; I am not able to read this high mathematics, but this kind of differential equation seem very interesting), I've asked to me questions likes as the following, where $\eta(s)$ the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function), and $\zeta(s)$ the **Riemann Zeta function**

> **Question.** Are there complex numbers $a_2,a_1,a_0$ such that if $$\Im(a_2\eta''(s)+a_1\eta'(s)+a_0\eta(s))<0$$
>   holds for $0< \Re s<\frac{1}{2} $ implies $$\Re\zeta(s)>\frac{1}{2}?$$ **Thanks in advance.**

Excuse me, previous question **was modified** to fix a typo.

I believe that my problem is well-possed. Why it and no other? My only purpose is learn if such question is easy to deduce what are the key computations, and if it is absurd then know one few more about these special functions.

Comment: I am able to compute derivatives of the Dirichlet eta function, and bounds, but I believe that my computations were no goods. Please if my question is not well-possed add a message to improve my question. This kind of computations are appreciated for me. Thanks.

Comment: $0< \left| s \right|<\frac{1}{2}$ should be $0< \Re s <\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Yes, I thought/wanted write it, was a typo, but I did not dare to do this change, now since no one has already answered the question, and my only purpose is see this type I improve the **Question.** Very thanks much @mike

Comment: **If my Question has meaning then my intuition say my that your answer should be very nice in their details, and it, your answer widely applicable to a large audience.** Thans in advance, I hope details in your answer that we can learn, and accept the bounty [+50] early, After there is an answer I will delete this comment, it is only to encourage to the people to answer my question. **The references of previous user are very useful.**

Answer (score 1):

You may check two preprints by Hisashi Kobayashi  (2016) :

1. "Some results on the $ξ(s)$ and $Ξ(t)$ functions associated with Riemann's $ζ(s)$ function" [arXiv:1603.02954](http://arxiv.org/abs/1603.02954)
2. "Local Extrema of the $Ξ(t)$ Function and The Riemann Hypothesis" [arXiv:1603.02911](http://arxiv.org/abs/1603.02911)

And one paper by Sondow, J. and C. Dumitrescu (2010):

“A monotonicity property of Riemann’s xi function and a reformulation of the Riemann hypothesis,”
Periodic math. Hung. 60 I (2010), 37-40. Also available at [arXiv:1005.1104](http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.1104)

Sondow, J. and C. Dumitrescu prove that Riemann's $\xi(\sigma+it)$ function is strictly increasing (respectively, strictly decreasing) in modulus $|\xi(\sigma+it)|$ along every horizontal (in $\sigma$ direction) half-line in any zero-free, open right (respectively, left) half-plane. A corollary is a reformulation of the Riemann Hypothesis.

Kobayashi's preprints showed that the derivatives of the modulus of a function relates to various real or imaginary parts of that function.

Comment: Very thanks much @mike, I will open this articles from these authors, that I know yer his names by the quality of their mathematics, and try unerstand some easy details from those. I am waiting more answers for my previous **Question.** Very thanks much for your attention and answer, and the explanation of the abstract.